# Scale QGraphicsItem About an Arbitrary Point

Tags: qt, scale

I'm trying to scale an object about the mouse cursor. I'm getting the mouse position easily enough, and I can scale the object no problem using item->setScale(n). However, I'm not sure how to actually incorporate the translation to account for the arbitrary point.

Is there a way to set the scale center? If not, how should I go about doing this?

This is what I have so far for my zoom in:

```
center = this->mapFromParent(center);
qDebug() << center;
this->setTransformOriginPoint(center);
QTransform transform;
transform = transform.scale(transform.m11() * 1.05, transform.m22() * 1.05);
this->setTransform(transform, true);
this->setTransformOriginPoint(0, 0);
```

Comment: Is the `jqtransform` tag relevant?

Comment: No, I actually have no idea how that got there. Thanks for the heads up :)

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at QGraphicsItem::setTransformOriginPoint(). It takes the position in item coordinates, so you'll probably have to map the mouse position to item coordinates.

I think this seems to be working as you expect:

```
class Scene : public QGraphicsScene
{
public:

    QGraphicsItem* item;

    Scene(QObject* parent = nullptr) 
        : QGraphicsScene(parent)
    {
        setSceneRect(0, 0, 500, 500);
        item = addRect(200, 200, 100, 100, QPen(Qt::black), QBrush(Qt::red));
    }

    void wheelEvent(QGraphicsSceneWheelEvent* event) 
    {
        /*Scale 0.2 each turn of the wheel (which is usually 120.0 eights of degrees)*/ 
        qreal scaleFactor = 1.0 + event->delta() * 0.2 / 120.0;             
        item->setTransformOriginPoint(item->mapFromScene(event->scenePos()));
        item->setScale(item->scale() * scaleFactor);
    }   
};

int main(int argc, char ** argv)
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);

    Scene* scene = new Scene;

    QGraphicsView view(scene);

    view.resize(600, 600);
    view.show();

    return a.exec();
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately, it doesn't seem to be working. I updated the question